# How to run a stored procedure continuosly with out timer in WCF

Tags: wcf

I want to execute a stored procedure continuously in a WCF application and without use of timer the stored procedure needs to be executed.

I tried with the timer and it works but how can I achieve with out using the timer in WCF?

Thanks in advance,

Prasad

Answer (score 1):

```
while(true)
{
    CallStoredProcedure()
}
```

What are you doing with the results though? I can't see why you would need to constantly call an SP. You probably need to redesign how you are doing this.

Comment: Actually one sp need to run continously if any error occurs in the application then that particular value needs to be recorded.

Comment: Is the SP your error logging SP? Then it doesn't need to run continuously. It needs to run when an error occurs.

Comment: Inorder to know when the dead lock occurs we dont know so the sp will insert the records continously and we can know that if there are any dead locks occurred.